# preprocessor errors of catkin_make

Tags: catkin-make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear ALL

Recently I want to transplant an old version code to Ubuntu 14.04 with ROS Indigo. But when I catkin_make the old code, there are many preprocessor errors like:

```
In file included from /usr/include/math.h:32:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath:44,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/complex:44,
                 from /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/Core:28,
                 from /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/Dense:1,
                 from /home/cheng/catkin_ws/src/pioneer_neo/neo_3dlabelling/src/include/generic_utils.h:4,
                 from /home/cheng/catkin_ws/src/pioneer_neo/neo_3dlabelling/./src/include/features.h:20,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/4.8/bits/os_defines.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/4.8/bits/c++config.h:426,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/cstddef:41,
                 from /usr/include/boost/config/select_stdlib_config.hpp:18,
                 from /usr/include/boost/config.hpp:40,
                 from /usr/include/boost/cstdint.hpp:36,
                 from /usr/include/pcl-1.7/pcl/pcl_macros.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/pcl-1.7/pcl/point_types.h:42,
                 from /home/cheng/catkin_ws/src/pioneer_neo/neo_3dlabelling/src/include/point_types.h:19,
                 from /home/cheng/catkin_ws/src/pioneer_neo/neo_3dlabelling/src/include/global_define.h:19,
                 from /home/cheng/catkin_ws/src/pioneer_neo/neo_3dlabelling/src/graeae.cpp:16:

/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/huge_val.h:26:18: error: missing binary operator before token "("
 #if __GNUC_PREREQ(3,3)
                  ^
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/huge_val.h:28:20: error: missing binary operator before token "("
 #elif __GNUC_PREREQ(2,96)
```

I am just a new beginner and I google many websites. But I still did not find the solution. Could anyone give me some suggestions? Thank you so much!

Henry

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213423/preprocessor-errors-of-catkin_make/) by [Zhao Cheng](https://answers.ros.org/users/10111/zhao-cheng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2015-07-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2015-07-10**:
What previous ROS version did it work with?

**Comment by [Zhao Cheng](https://answers.ros.org/users/10111/zhao-cheng/) on 2015-07-10**:
In Ubuntu12.04 with groovy, it can works well. It is compiled using rosmake. But in Ubuntu 14.04 with indigo, it is compiled using catkin_make. The preprocessor errors occurred.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2015-07-10**:
Did you convert your package from rosmake to catkin_make?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2015-07-10**:
Have you tried building it with rosmake, as before?

**Comment by [Zhao Cheng](https://answers.ros.org/users/10111/zhao-cheng/) on 2015-07-10**:
yep, I converted it from rosmake to catkin_make through modifying CMakeLists.txt.  It can be built through rosmake in groove in Ubuntu12.04

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2015-07-10**:
This looks to be just a C++ error where `__GNUC_PREREQ` is not yet defined: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042795/help-with-this-compile-error You might just try including `#include <cstring>` first thing in the files which fail to compile.

**Comment by [Zhao Cheng](https://answers.ros.org/users/10111/zhao-cheng/) on 2015-07-10**:
Many thanks for everybody's help. I built it using rosmake instead of catkin_make in Indigo in Ubuntu 14.04. The preprocessor errors did not occur again. Why using catkin_make,  the preprocessor errors occurred.  It really confuses me.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2015-07-10**:
That is a mystery.  I'm not aware of any difference in the two that could manifest like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Many thanks for everybody's help. Maybe I made some mistakes of the path of include file. I put my include files in the src subdirectories. When I # the ./src/include/  and  ./src/include/impl/ in CmakeLists.txt:

include_directories(
./src/include/
./src/include/impl/
${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})

the preprocessor errors disappeared.

---

Originally posted by [Zhao Cheng](https://answers.ros.org/users/10111/zhao-cheng/) with karma: 46 on 2015-07-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0